# Is there some temperature at which all "5w" oils should have about the same viscosity?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, automotive-engineering

Is there some temperature at which all "5w" motor oils should have about the same viscosity?  (5w-20, 5w-30, 5w-40, 5w-50, etc.) 
I am looking for SAE or ASTM wording or chart that says it straight out, by definition.  But it's not exactly jumping out at me.
Maybe it is not that simple?  Maybe they don't define it that way? 
Could I find the answer by using ASTM D341 graph paper to chart out a few oils with known mfr specs for viscosity at 40 deg C and 100 deg C ? (which they all have)

One little problem there is I would need the chart that covers from 100 deg C all the way down to, I don't know where, but some pretty low temps, and I can't see the limits on any of their 7 charts.  And I don't know if those charts are accurate for modern motor oil either.

Comment: Please provide the charts or at least the links to the charts you refer to.

Comment: You might find this helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_oil

Comment: The numbers in SAE oil grades are not numerical values of anything. They are just identification numbers. The only thing you can say in general is that higher numbers mean higher viscosity. In fact the numbering system was changed at some time in the past, when new engine designs with low-viscosity oil specification would have meant using grades with negative numbers in the original system.

Comment: It used to be "saybolt seconds" ; the time it took an amount of oil to run out a specific orifice  ( per ASTM D-88).

Comment: Solar Mike - I don't have any of these charts but the ASTM web page where you can buy them is here: https://www.astm.org/Standards/D341.htm   I think it would be the item called "Printed Pads".   You can buy the whole set (there are 7 sets) for 248 USD.  Or, if you pick the Printed Pads link, it takes you to a page where you can buy individual pads for 33 USD each.  I would maybe actually buy one of those if I knew which one would cover the range, and if I knew that they are supposed to be accurate down to 0 deg F and lower.

Comment: Seems the dollar sign throws the formatting here into a tizzy.   LOL.  So I put "USD" instead.  I wonder how they handle that in the financial section.

Comment: Widman International has a graphical calculator online that I'm trying out to see what happens.  It seems to run OK in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome (it needs Flash).  Here is a link to it:  https://www.widman.biz/English/Calculators/Graph.html

Comment: Widman has another page where they have graphed 7 different "typical" motor oils, including 5w30, 5w40, and 5w50.  But they only take it down to 0 deg C.   Not cold enough really.  But the 5w30 is not converging with the other two 5w oils.  Here's a link.  You can go to this page and then pick their link for the temperature range 0 to 30 deg C.  https://www.widman.biz/English/Tables/Graph-motors.html

Comment: Solar Mike - I'm still kind of digesting the Wikipedia article.  It's a lot like other articles I've found about it.  Very clear about the number on the right which is determined at 100 deg C.   But kind of ambiguous about the number on the left, the "w" number.   Seems like the "w" number is determined by performance at very low temps, like -30, -35 deg C.  But some articles I've found say the "w" number is determined at 0 deg F.   One article I found says both !!